# How to write a program in java where summation of the given formula will be printed?

Tags: java

Formula is : {N(N/1)^2}/4

where N = 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0 ;

I am very new in java that's why facing problems,but I am thinking about to do something with loop&array.Where all float numbers will be stored in array and a terrifying loop will be add those numbers in a sum variable.Please,Let me know if you have any better idea to solve this problem.Also I will be glad if you can share piece of codes which will be written in java programming language.
Thanks is advance :)

Comment: What is your current code? Please refer to [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Post the code you already wrote to solve this and explain exactly what is not working with that code.

Comment: Those number looks like a sequence with constant difference between the values so if this is the case then there is no need to store them in an array. Other than that I suggest you follow some java tutorials first, there are plenty around and you shouldn't need to dive to deep into java to start working on your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Dummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double min = 0.0;
        double max = 3.0;
        double d = 0.5;

        for (double n = min; n <= max; n+=d) {
            double result =  (Math.pow(n*(n/1), 2)) / 4; // {N(N/1)^2}/4
            System.out.print(result + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
result : 0.0, 0.015625, 0.25, 1.265625, 4.0, 9.765625, 20.25.
```

You can change the `min`/`max` values to change the range you want.
as you can see you don't need any data structure(array) for this problem unless you want to save the result for another use.